# How to return a function instead of only values

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Here is my code on server side

```
socket.on('new message', msg => {
   io.emit('new message', {
     name: socket.username,
     msg: msg   
   });
  });
```

and on client side

```
socket.on('new message', function(data) {
    var item = document.createElement('div');
    item.textContent = data.name+data.msg;
    messages.appendChild(item);
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
   });
```

it works but I want to go secure and expose source code as least as possible so I wonder if this possible to do it the other way around, like this?

```
socket.on('new message', msg => {
   io.emit('new message', () => {
    var item = document.createElement('div');
    item.textContent = socket.username+msg;
    messages.appendChild(item);  
   });
  });

socket.on('new message', function(data) {
    data();
   });
```

this wont work but if there is a way please let me know.

Comment: you can't control the client like that from the server side. the javascript has to run on the client.

Comment: I don't think you can send non-serializable data over `socket.io`

Comment: More broadly, if being able to read your JavaScript source code opens security holes for you, your architecture is inherently flawed. The nature of in-browser JavaScript is that of needing to transmit the source code in a browser-readable format, at the very least.

Comment: you mean I would need to serialize the function so the client can receive it?

Comment: @snksaint a function is not serializable... you could send a string and evaluate it in the browser, but evaluating string-stored code on the client is by default a recipe for disaster. 

Client-ran code cannot be trusted, by default, you need to make sure your server validates all input data, but on client-side, not much you can do about it (**everything** client-side is user-modifiable)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using `socket.io`, which sends JSON data over WebSockets, and JavaScript functions can't be serialized as JSON.

You could achieve this functionality by sending code as a string and calling `eval` to run it in your current context.

But aside from this being insecure (If the code sent can be affected by user input, and without proper sanitization it could lead to remote code execution on the browser), people could still see the code which is being sent and ran in their Browser's Network tab or by other means of inspecting network traffic.

At the end of the day, you can't really hide what runs on the browser, you can make effort to obfuscate it (There are plenty of tools that do this), but this just makes it harder to figure out the functionality, not impossible.

Comment: not trying to hide it, but rather prevent users from changing it on their end.

Comment: @snksaint A competent enough user could achieve this regardless in plenty ways, since the code is running in their browser on their local machine. One such example is simply connecting themselves to your WebSocket server from the console and running whatever functionality they want.

Comment: @snksaint nothing prevents users from changing anything in javascript on the browsers. You must do your server-side validations and sanitizations where applicable and not use client-side code for backend algorithms. In your specific case, what could prevent a user from just changing the prototype of `socket.on` and do whatever they please with the data (or method, or whatever) emitted from the backend?

Comment: so you mean they can read all I have in my server side js file?? From `const app = require("express")();` all the way down??

Comment: @snksaint No, only the code that is being sent to the browser, you can't (fully) hide anything there. Code on your server-side (or backend) cannot be viewed/affected by end-users.

Comment: @snksaint no, server side code is not modifiable... client-side code is. Anything running on the client is modifiable (including the function you want to send over `socket.io`, because you are ultimately running it on the client)

Comment: @snksaint They can't access code on your server normally. BUT you are proposing sending a function to the client and they can see the function in the packet you send to the client

Comment: I see. Well, can I at least send the values already wrapped in html? Like instead of `msg: msg ` send `msg: '<span>'+msg+'</span>'` that would save me a lot of coding.

Comment: You could, but if `msg` contains anything from user input, without proper sanitization it would lead to an XSS vulnerability. You would also have to set `innerHTML` in your frontend code as opposed to building the desired structure using `document.createElement`, which is preferred.

Comment: it is properly satinized but I cant pass it through. It is converted into plan text.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry but I don't understand why you would hide appending a div to the dom from the user.

Any user that really wanted to view the clients logic can do just that, as everything is already available to them. If you are trying to 'obfuscate' your code and logic, then I suggest you think once again.

Edit: If you really want to continue, then paste this into the console tab of your browser's devtools.

```js
function a(b) {
  return b + 1;
}

String(a);
```

you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: I dont want to obfuscate itits just more practical to me to do this: `username : '<span>'+username+'</span>';` than this `var item = document.createElement('span');
    item.textContent = data.username;
    users.appendChild(item);`

Comment: @snksaint That is NOT what your example of what you wanted to be able to do in your original question did.

Comment: its basically the same, i want to send html over from the server so the client executes

Comment: So you want an xss attack to happen on your website? Alright go ahead.

Comment: I dont get it, shouldnt it be harder to get one of those if the file is on your server?

Comment: Well think about it. You no longer are doing `.createElement`, `.innerText`, or `.appendChild`. And since you have html tags in there (`<span>`), you would have to do something like `.innerHTML`. Now what if a user decides to call themselves `<script>alert('xss')</script>`?

Comment: you mean set a username like that? They cant. Names like that are not allowed at all by the system and there is no way they cant bypass that.

Comment: It's not worth arguing with you because its clear you don't know much about xss yet. But I will tell you that what you are trying to do is pointless.

Comment: Im not arguing. Im just asking a question. How can anybody inject an attack if they cant send html over the server?

Comment: @snksaint Now its way more clear you don't know what xss is. Please search up what an xss attack is. Here is one resource https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/

Comment: I know what an xss attack is but you are not answering my question. I am telling you users CANNOT input html or any other code in any way so my question is, how can they still send an xss attack?